# Excel 2013 grid lookup generate SQL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that needs exporting into MYSQL. This sheet contains a grid with the rows being components and columns being products.

Column A holds the component name with columns b onwards  using row 1 as product names.

The grid is a grid of components that make up that product in row 1 of the column. not all components are used in a product, for example:

`xxxxxxxxxxx | product 1 | product 2
component 1 |     1     |     0
component 2 |     0     |     1 
component 3 |     0     |     10`

and so on. I am trying to get a formula that can check each column against each row, if the column has a value > 0 or not blank then grab the product name, component name and the value ready to be used to generate SQL (i already have component ids etc)

is this possible? I have seen reverse lookups and lookups using grids but not to this level..

would be very grateful to any excel wizards out there that can save me hours of manually doing this (there are 102 products with ~ 1000 different components..)

Comment: Generate them for all and then use regex to remove 0 value rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) followed by filter to delete rows with `Value` 0.